# ¿Como hacer que mi pagina sea responsiva con cualquier dispositivo?

Tags: html, css, web

Soy principiante en esto y no logro conseguir que mi pagina sea compatible con otros dispositivos, es decir, que en mi pc se ve bien pero cuando abro el link en el telefono se ve descuadrada.

Vista en pc:

[image: Vista en pc]

Y asi se ve en android :

[image: Vista en telefono]

Si necesitan el codigo avisenme que se los dare

Comment: Saludos. Lo más conocido y te ahorra mucho es https://getbootstrap.com/ hay otras; mira la parte de **Grid system**.

Comment: Échale una mirada a flexbox.

Comment: Hola @Waldo, debes utilizar `viewport` combinada con **_Media Queries_** para que puedas adaptar tu sitio Web a diferentes tamaños de pantallas. En cuanto me desocupe un poco te publico una respuesta donde se explica el proceso basado en lo que has publicado. Recuerda que lo que buscas  lleva el nombre de  _Responsive Web Design_.

Comment: @Waldo, quería añadir algo. Debes publicar el código que generó la vista que has compartido acá para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Te recomienod poner tu código con un [snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%C3%A9-es-stack-snippet) para obtener respuestas más enfocadas a tu problema.

Comment: Waldo, bucaste en internet?

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap

Como te comentaron, un framework que te hace eso y es popular por su sistema de rejilla es [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap), que puedes obtener desde https://getbootstrap.com/, hasta este momento las verisones estables dependen de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), lo cual va a cambiar en muy poco tiempo.

La ecplicación rápida es que en este framework agregas clases a tus entidades html, y estas permiten configurar la rejilla por tí, hacienod que sea responsiva en múltiples resoluciones, incluso puedes especificar como quieres que se vea en cada resolución.

La rejilla o grilla, tiene máximo 12 columnas por fila, permitiéndote hacer tu maquetado de manera rápida y bastante intuitiva a mi parecer.

### Level

Este es un framework de un amigo y en el cual he colaborado un poco, puedes descargarlo desde: https://jorgeantrax.github.io/level-docs/ usa el mismo principio de las 12 columnas y actualmente tiene preconfiguradas 8 opciones de resoluciones que se agregan mediante clases:

- mobile
- touch
- only-touch
- tablet
- only-tablet
- desktop
- only-desktop
- widescreen

Te dejo un ejemplo de layout de este framework que lo hace bastante particular

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/level-css-framework@0.6.0/js/level.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/level-css-framework@0.6.0/css/level.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<layout>
  <header class="color-primary">@content</header>
  <navbar class="color-warning">@content</navbar>
  <sidebar class="color-dark">@content</sidebar>
  <main class="color-info-lighten-4">
    <social>
      <media>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4clCrPXBy2rJEVFHYoybzHQmxvcFXkCV8u4IDrLqbyocvqRt0Zg">
      </media>
      <content>
        <header>
          <info>Level CSS</info>
        </header>
        <section>
          <p>Un potente framework basado en <b>flexbox</b>y etiquetas personalizadas.</p>
        </section>
        <footer>
          <icon>
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
          </icon>
        </footer>
      </content>
      <close>
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
      </close>
    </social>
  </main>
  <footer class="color-danger">@content</footer>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en este caso te puedo recomendar dos cosas:

1. Que aprendas responsive web design, y aprendas a usar los media query en CSS el cual te permite darle un estilo CSS distinto algún elemento de tu HTML según el tamaño del dispositivo donde se despliega el contenido. Te dejo un link donde te explican de una manera resumida el tema:

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

2. Que adaptes tu proyecto a la librería de Bootstrap, la cual te ofrece muchas herramientas para ahorrarte escribir bastante código, te dejo el link para que lo revises, es muy importante que adquieras este conocimiento para tus próximos proyectos:

Link: https://getbootstrap.com/